# Scheduled runnable invoked only once on startup

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that has registered a `BroadcastReceiver` to get `BOOT_COMPLETED` (I have the required permissions and everything configured in the manifest).

When it gets it, it schedules a runnable to run every X minutes:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    }
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

The same method is invoked also manually when the user launches the app.

- when the app is manually launched, the scheduled runnable runs as expected
- when the app has received `BOOT_COMPLETED` the scheduled runnable runs only once (successfully), then stops and never runs again. There are no exceptions, but it doesn't run.

Why might that be happening?

Comment: Have you done a thread dump when this abnormal situation occurs to confirm that it isn't running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why might that be happening?

Because your process was terminated, taking your `ScheduledExecutorService` along with it.

Use `AlarmManager` to get control periodically.

Comment: Thanks. How do I run a `Runnable` (or simply a snippet of code) through the AlarmManager (how to make a PendingIntent that is simply executing a piece of code)?

Comment: @Bozho: "How do I run a Runnable (or simply a snippet of code) through the AlarmManager" -- you don't. "how to make a PendingIntent that is simply executing a piece of code" -- if the code will run in a millisecond or so, put it in a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`. If the code will run for more than that, put it in an `IntentService`. Note that if you will use a `_WAKEUP` alarm, to have your code run even if the device is asleep, use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or my `WakefulIntentService`.